# Problem while installing keystone for openstack (stein)

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

we are a group of french students in networks, and we need to get openstack working for a school project. We are curently facing an issue while installing keystone. After following the official [openstack guide](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/fr/install-guide-rdo/keystone-install.html), when trying the service, we get the following error:

```
    [root@localhost ~]# openstack project create --domain default   --description "Service Project" service
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://controller:5000/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Unable to establish connection to http://controller:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f60f19af9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Nom ou service inconnu',))

tail /var/log/keystone/keystone.log
    2019-10-03 14:24:35.943 4778 WARNING keystone.access_rules_config.backends.json [-] No config file found for access rules, application credential access rules will be unavailable.: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/keystone/access_rules.json'
```

We are installing the stein version
Does anyone know how to solve the problem? We can include some others log if needed. We are two who tried and get the same error.
Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error is self explanatory. 
You are missing a config file which governs access to openstack endpoints.
You can use copy it from unittest cases and put in /etc/keystone folder.

For your convenience here is url to file:

https://fossies.org/linux/misc/openstack/keystone-15.0.0.tar.gz/keystone-15.0.0/keystone/tests/unit/config_files/access_rules.json?m=t